# Loading an XML file into a dataset using SSIS

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis

Is it possible to parse & load an xml file with optional elements/attributes using SQL Server Integration Service 2005? Any examples/pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse it an xml CLOB using T-SQL constructs now: [SO search for SQL Server and xml tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xml+sql-server?sort=votes)

I think it would be clumsy using SSIS.

Do you have to use SSIS particularly?

Comment: I've used SSIS to import complex XML before. It was a win because of the amount of defaulting and consistency checking that was necessary before the data could be imported. It's also quite fast, especially so in the 2008 version.

Comment: @John: Fair enough. I've used XQuery in T-SQL wfor smaller, well defined schema. It depends on what OP wants to do, really.

Comment: @John: Can you please explain the steps needed to import that XML data?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/687913/what-is-the-largest-xml-file-ssis-can-extract-data-from/687976#687976 and let me know if you need more information after that. It's pretty long, but could use pictures.